# is this a right query to find a table in database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

is this a right query to find a table in database ?

```
$checktable=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT $n FROM jma 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN('file','recived')");


$userResult=mysql_num_rows($checktable);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$photo);

    if ($userResult == 0)
    {
        echo"table does not exist";
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_query("insert into $n (recived) values('$photo')") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "Your data is SuccessFully Addedd............";
    }
```

Comment: try `WHERE lower(COLUMN_NAME) IN('file','recived')`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with the SHOW command provides MySQL, something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW tables LIKE 'table_name';");
$exists = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($exists == 1) {
    // Your code here
} else {
    // Your code here
}
```

I have not tested, but should work without problem.

A greeting.

Answer (score 0):

Using information_schema:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'your_db' 
    AND table_name = 'your_table'
LIMIT 1;
```